# I am using angular code to call the rest api and display it on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

The following code is my   viewall.ts code

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-viewall',
  templateUrl: './viewall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./viewall.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
 export class RestComponent  {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  configUrl = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
  getConfig() {
   return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```

This is my app.module.ts code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from'@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestComponent } from './rest/rest.component';
import { ViewallComponent } from './viewall/viewall.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RestComponent,
    ViewallComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

it is giving e the following error ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(6,10): error TS2305: Module '"E:/paramount/paramount/src/app/viewall/viewall.component"' has no exported member 'ViewallComponent'.

Comment: The code in you've listed above under `viewall.ts` is exporting a class called `RestComponent`, not `ViewallComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Where is the exported class inside viewall.component.ts? You should be exporting a class from the component.

Haven't you declared RestComponent as Injectable and that too inside viewall.ts, and then you are importing it from rest.component file inside app.module.ts.

Try to move the RestComponent from the declarations array to providers array and also the import from the correct file.

Hope it helps.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from'@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RestComponent } from './rest/rest.component';
import { ViewallComponent } from './viewall/viewall.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ViewallComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    RestComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Your viewall.component.ts should be exporting a class and look like this:-

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-viewall',
  templateUrl: './viewall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./viewall.component.css']
})
export class ViewallComponent{}
```

Answer (score 0):

injectable service is in providers

you can try with this solution.

```
providers: [
    RestComponent,
],


declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ViewallComponent
],
```

> In viewall component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-viewall',
  templateUrl: './viewall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./viewall.component.css']
})
export class ViewallComponent{
    constructor() { }
}

@Injectable()
 export class RestComponent  {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  configUrl = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
  getConfig() {
   return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```